# Limits problem of $0/0$ form

Tags: limits

I am given problem as $$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} (\frac{-ax + \sin(x-1)+a}{x+\sin(x-1)-1})^\frac{1-x}{1-\sqrt{x})}$$ so what would be largest non negative $a$ such that value of limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.
Now since both power and base are of indeterminate form so I solved them individually as 
$$ \frac{1-x}{(1-\sqrt{x})}= \frac{(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x}}{(1-\sqrt{x} )} = 1+\sqrt{x}$$ now putting limit it becomes $2$ now since base is of  $0/0$ form I used L'Hopitals Rule hence it became $$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} (\frac{-a + \cos(x-1)}{1+\cos(x-1)})$$ putting limits it becomes $$(\frac{-a + 1}{1+1})^2$$ which should be $1/4$ as given in the problem
$$(\frac{-a + 1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}$$
 but greatest non negative value that satisfies given result seems to be $2$ but correct answer is $0$ , where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $a=2$ then near $x=1$ you have $\dfrac{-a+1}{2} \approx -0.5$ and $1+\sqrt{x} \approx 2$ but you cannot conclude that  $\left(\dfrac{-a+1}{2}\right)^{1+\sqrt{x}} \approx 0.25$ in the real numbers.

For example, what do you think $(-0.500005)^{1.99995}$ would be?

So you want $\dfrac{-a+1}{2}$ to be non-negative, which requires $a$ to be less than $1$.